# jQuery Image Swapping with li's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list of li's in a ul with a class of "color-boxes". Each one of these li's all have a data attribute of "data-color". These data attributes are also found in the matching images that correspond to each li. What I am trying to do is get each image that goes with each li to be swapped out when you hover or click on the li with the matching data-attribute. 
Here is my current jquery. Please keep in mind I have no idea what I am doing when it comes to jQuery:

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    // foreach each ul.color-boxes li

```
jQuery("ul.color-boxes li").each(function() {

                    // bind click event 
    jQuery(this).bind('click', function() {

        jQuery("li").attr("data-color");



    });   
});

jQuery("figure.main-image img").each(function() {

    jQuery("img").attr("data-color");

});

//ul.color-boxes li === figure.main-image img
    function showImg(strShow, strHide) 
        {
            // hide all figure.main-image img
            jQuery("figure.main-image img[data-color='"+ strShow +"']").show();

            document.getElementById(strShow).style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById(strHide).style.display = 'none';
        }
```

});

Anyone have any help they can send my way?

Comment: I was using that function to call it in buttons I embedded into the li's. But I was told there was an easier way to do all of this (jQuery) but I have little to no experience with that language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that is solution you search for:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("ul.color-boxes li").on("click", function() {    // foreach each ul.color-boxes li
        var sColorVal = jQuery(this).attr("data-color");
        if (typeof(sColorVal) != "undefined") {
            jQuery("figure.main-image img[data-color='"+ sColorVal +"']").show();   // show images with clicked "data-color" value
            jQuery("figure.main-image img[data-color!='"+ sColorVal +"']").hide();  // hide images with deffrent "data-color" value
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Is there any way I can add a hover state to this as well, along with the click event? That way whether you hover or click on the li, the image will swap

Comment: Of course. You can place events space-separated: `on("click hover", function() { ... })`. Or you can attach one more event: `on("click", function() { ... }).on("hover", function() { ... })`

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code a little, also tried to add comments where necessary, hopefully enough ;)

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){

      var strShow="";
      var strHide="";

      function showImg() 
      {

         // if a image is already visible and if it is not the same image as the image that is to be made visible
         if(strHide.length>0 && strShow!=strHide){
               // hide previous figure.main-image img
               jQuery("figure.main-image img[data-color='"+ strHide+"']").hide();
          }

          jQuery("figure.main-image img[data-color='"+ strShow +"']").show();

          //Keeping track of the currently visible image to hide later if required

          strHide=strShow;
    }

    jQuery("ul.color-boxes li").each(function() {

                // bind click event 
               jQuery(this).bind('click', function() {

               //getting the data-color to associate with the current image to show
                strShow=jQuery(this).attr("data-color");

               //calling the function to show the current image
           showImg();


          });   
      });

    });
```

Comment: Is there any way I can add a hover state to this as well, along with the click event? That way whether you hover or click on the li, the image will swap